# How to write into a csv file path from jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a jmeter script where i am randomly generating Email and i want to write email into a csv file.
I have tried couple of ways but did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is using [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property. Given you have a JMeter Variable called `email`

- Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

  ```
  sample_variables=email
  ```
- Restart JMeter to pick the property up
- Next time you run your JMeter test you will be able to see an extra column called `email` in the .jtl results file containing the variable value for each and every sampler

---

Alternative way is using [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223). The relevant Groovy code to append the value of `email` variable into a file would be something like:

```
def emails = new File('emails.csv')
emails << vars.get('email')
emails << System.getProperty('line.separator')
```

See [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.

Answer (score 0):

Add a beanshell POSTProcessor and write down the following code
[image]